# php code igniter select retrieve issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am using Code Igniter Framework for website,

This is a technical article website and I am adding articles of different languages.

In that when I save the article along with the code for e.g. It inserted properly in the database.

```
&lt;pre class="prettyprint" id="html"&gt;
&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"&gt;
&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd"&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
    &lt;meta name="copyright" content="Atos Origin" /&gt;
    &lt;title&gt;Select Option Demo Using Tapestry&lt;/title&gt;    
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
    &lt;h1&gt;Payment Card Demo&lt;/h1&gt;              
    &lt;form t:type="form" t:id="cardForm" id="cardForm" method="post"&gt;
        &lt;t:label for="cardTypes"/&gt;
        &lt;t:select t:id="cardTypes"/&gt;
    &lt;/form&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
&lt;/pre&gt;
```

But when I retrieve it from database to edit, it is converted in actual code.

```
<pre class="prettyprint" id="html">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="copyright" content="Atos Origin" />
    <title>Select Option Demo Using Tapestry</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Payment Card Demo</h1>              
    <form t:type="form" t:id="cardForm" id="cardForm" method="post">
        <t:label for="cardTypes"/>
        <t:select t:id="cardTypes"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

But don't want such conversion, so is there any solution?

Comment: Databases won't convert the text. that's not their job. Are you viewing this in a browser? Remember that browsers are going to take those `&lt;` and `&gt;` character entities and display them as their rendered equivalents...

Answer (score 2):

There is a PHP Solution:

To encode HTML to character equivalents use:

```
string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = 'UTF-8' [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

To decode to html use:

```
string html_entity_decode ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = 'UTF-8' ]] )
```

Suggestion:

I would not encode the html to special characters when inserting into the database, only when pulling it out with the function specified above.